# Error in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection External Hard Drive R

Tags: r, imaging

I have a code block of the following:

```
# Obtain records from all patients
patientDir <- sort(list.dirs(path = "sample_images", full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE))

dataframes <- list()
i = 1
while(i<19){
  # Strip the patient out
  patient <- coreHist(patientDir[i])

  print("1")
  setwd("/Volumes/HUGE storage drive/")
  exists<- file.exists(patientDir[i])

  print(exists)

  # Extract the relevant information from the patient
  dicom <- readDICOM(patientDir[i])
  dicomdf <- dicomTable(dicom$hdr)  
  patient_id <- dicomdf$`0010-0020-PatientID`[1] 

  print("2")

  # Normalize their VX's
  sum<- sum(patient$histData$finalFreq)

  print("3")

  # Create the new VX's
  patient$histData$finalFreq_scaled <- (patient$histData$finalFreq/sum)

  print("4")

  # Add their ID
  patient$histData$patientid <- patient_id

  print("5")

  # Keep only the important columns
  patient$histData <- patient$histData[c("patientid", "Var1", "finalFreq_scaled")]

  print("6")

  # Add these dataframes to a list for better recall afterwards
  dataframes[[i]] <- patient$histData

  print("7")

  # Additional code to transpose and merge dataframes
  if(i == 1){
    wide_df <- patient$histData
  }else{
    wide_df <- rbind(wide_df,patient$histData )
  }

  print("8")

  print(paste(c("Patient", i), sep ="", collapse = "-"))

  i = i+1
}
```

However, after a (seemingly random) number of iterations, the code fails right after the line "print("1")" with the following error:

```
Error in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection
```

The working directory is set to an external hard drive as the "sample_images" folder is 62GB large. I thought perhaps there was a timeout connection with R studio and my external hard drive so I tried to "remain active" on my computer, I've also tried resetting the working directory after each iteration to make sure it can find the file.

When it fails on a certain patient, I check manually to see if that file does indeed exist, and it does. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually not sure why the error was happening, but to fix it I simply added a "try" statement:

```
  attempt <- 1
  while(is.null(dicom) && attempt <= 3){
    attempt <- attempt + 1
    try(
      dicom <- readDICOM(patientDir[i])
    )  
  }
```

This did indeed work.